# MVC - How to correctly call partial view in master layout page?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

**Question Background**

I have a page called 'ProductDetail.cshtml that uses a masterLayout page. This MasterLayout contains a PartialView that populates a drop-down menu with 'cart items' showing how many items there are as shown:

[image]

Currently, when a user adds an item to their cart a Modal pop-up shows the newly added item, after the modal is closed I need to update the cart drop down drop to show the newly updated cart item number in the MasterLayout.

**Code:**

'MasterLayout.cshtml' showing the 'Cart Item' drop down, The 'Cart' method returns back a PartialView.:

```
<form class="navbar-form pull-right">
     @Html.Action("MiniCart", "Cart")
</form>
```

'ProductDetail.cshtml' which uses MasterLayout.cshtml.

```
<script>

 $("#AddCartItem").click(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("AddToCart")',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            "id": $('#productId').val(),
            "qty": $('#productQty').val(),
            "name": $('#productName').text(),
            "price": $('#productPrice').text(),
            "brand": $('#productBrand').text(),
            "image": $('#productImage').val()
        },
        success: function (json) {

            for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++)
            {
                AddRows(json[i].CartItemImage,
                        json[i].CartItemName,
                        json[i].CartItemPrice,
                        json[i].CartItemQty,
                        json[i].CartItemBrand);
            }

            $("#dialog-example").modal('show');
        }
    });
});

$("#CloseModal").click(function (e) {

    $('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
        $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
    });

    //****Attempt to call the PartialView of the MasterLayout to update drop-down
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("MiniCart", "Cart")'
    });
 });
</script>
```

The above JQuery passes back a returned JSON object CartItems list in the 'success' method. The modal body table content is built up then when the users closes the modal (as denoted by the ID '#CloseModal' I want the PartialView to be recalled in the MasterLayout to update the CartItems drop-down to show the new value. Can anyone point me in the right direction of being able to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could call the cart action method with JQuery and then replace the content within the `form` with the new content.

**Example**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.get('@Html.Url("MiniCart", "Cart")', function(data) {
            $('.navbar-form').html(data);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your modal, add a form :

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("MiniCart","Cart",null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "cartDiv", OnSuccess = "$('#yourModalId').modal('hide');" }))
```

add a div with the UpdateTargetId on your template :

```
<form class="navbar-form pull-right">
    <div id="cartDiv">
         @Html.Action("MiniCart", "Cart")
    </div>
</form>
```

And change your close button on your modal to a submit type

note:
don't forget to add the script:

```
   <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
```